# PHP mysql bigint issue

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables with bigint:

```
table1
id bigint(20) PK autoincrement
name varchar(40),
text

table2
id bigint(20) PK autoincrement
created datetime
text_field
id_table1_ref bigint(20)
```

After inserting data into table1 and trying to insert table1.id into table2.id_table1_ref, 
the number is different, i.e.:

Number 1552545662588 from table1.t1 becomes 1552545662, or even worse, a negative number.

I know this is an issue with settings, but I can't figure out how to manage this.
I tried to set up signed/unasigned values for the fields, but it doesn't work.

This is happening on my UNIX local computer, on the server all is working ok, at least for now.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This may be a MySQL issue like you said, but also make sure that nothing in the PHP code is causing the numbers to be cast to PHP ints. MySQL bigints are bigger than PHP ints can handle so make sure you always keep it as a string in PHP.

Comment: Are you sure one of them is not bigint unsigned and the other signed? This would cause the problem you are describing.

Comment: @Alasdair yes, I'm sure ...

Comment: @MattBrowne thanks Matt, I took the wrong approach, I should treat them as strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to CONVERT it to a string in SQL before getting it into PHP. In PHP, you can use [GMP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) to handle the number.

MySQL docs on converting: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert

Answer (score 4):

It's also the case that PHP under at least some 64-bit operating systems (eg FreeBSD AMD64) uses an 8-byte int, verifiable by testing with

> echo 'Size of int is '.PHP_INT_SIZE ;

So if you're only going to be running a 64-bit operating system, you shouldn't need to manage the BIGINTs as strings in PHP.

Comment: according to http://windows.php.net/download/#x64, this will not work on Windows, but due to most servers are running Linux i give +1

Answer (score -2):

I solved this problem by change to another php version,that is changing from 64bit php version to 32bit php version. That really works for me.