# PHP MySQLi can't update field where specific BIGINTS

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I update over 50000 rows where BIGINT is always 13 - 14 numbers long. But there are some (very few, under 0.01%) ints which I can't use to update fields. Just try for yourself:

Create table(`artikel`) with fields:

- `field(BIGINT)` with value `4030521732735`
- `stuff(text)` with value `abc`

and then try:

```
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE artikel SET stuff = 'newabc' WHERE field = 4030521732735");
```

Isn't the field getting updated by you too? If yes, what could be wrong with this int? Any ideas how to fix this? Sorry for my bad english

**UPDATE:**

I tried this but it's also not working:

```
$bigint = gmp_init("4030521732735");
$bigint_string = gmp_strval($bigint);

mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE test SET stuff = 'newabc' WHERE field = $bigint_string");
```

and

```
$int = strval("4030521732735");

mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE test SET stuff = 'newabc' WHERE field = $int");
```

Comment: What mysql error are you getting?

Comment: did you check the return value for boolean false, check affected_rows(), try running the query manually yourself?

Comment: I think the problem is this value is out of range of `BIGINT`.

Comment: How to display errors? Sorry I'm pretty new to this

Comment: bigint is 64bit. you only need ~42 bits to represent your number. it's NOT a range issue.

Comment: `mysqli_query($con, ...) or die(mysqli_error($con))`

Comment: It seems to [work for me](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f23a3/1).

Comment: Are you using a prepared query in your PHP? Show the code that performs the actual query.

Comment: prepared query?? I test it in seperate another file where there is nothing but $con and the query, I also tested the query with other bigints and it works fine.

Comment: @spencer7593 The `UPDATE` statement has a `WHERE` clause, so it just updates that row.

Comment: @spencer7593 where I remove  WHERE field = 4030521732735 then every field is getting updated sucessfully, also the problem-BIGINTS

Comment: @Mike I ask my host to update the mysql version when mine isn't the newest one. What version do you have? Did you tried my problem on your server?

Comment: Could the problem be on php side, not working properly with bigints (depending on the underlying op-system)? For mysql bigints greater than php ints, you may need to treat them like strings php-side. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16374568/php-mysql-bigint-issue   (though in your test example, it seems to be literraly given in the sql string...)

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into a query.

Comment: If your test query really is as above (`"UPDATE artikel SET stuff = 'newabc' WHERE field = 4030521732735"`), php actually doesn't have to do any stuff with the bigint value, it's in a string.   But if your test looks like `$val=4030521732735; mysqli_query(... , "UPDATE ... where value=$val");` , it may happen under 32 bits systems that your value is out of bounds for php. So you should try `$val='4030521732735'`, php won't have out of bound problems (it's a string), then mysql will cast implicitely the string to a bigint.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79582/discussion-on-question-by-donbingo-php-mysqli-cant-update-field-where-specific).

Comment: @fpierrat I answered in chat now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem had in fact nothing to do with ints or bigints or whatever... quite a long discussion brought to the conclusion that strings were not properly escaped before sending to DB (strings occasionnaly containing quotes) ;-)