# PHP 7.4 laravel data saves garbage value

Tags: php, laravel, php-7.4

We are noticing a weird issue in Laravel 8 with PHP 7.4 version.

When we save data to the Mysql db, it is storing garbage value.

An example data:

```
$product = Product::create([
    'product_id' => 6791044858042,
    'inventory_id' => 42309695242426
]);
```

The same is happening using **$product = new Product()**;

The value in the DB is

```
"product_id":"701563066","inventory_id":"-27590470"
```

When we log the $product in the file just after saving, it has the correct value. The data is not re-saved and the data modified is notified either.

Inspected the max integer value for the column in db schema. It has bigint(20), I did change it to biging(100) and even varchar(255), yet it is the same result.

Further the garbage value is random and not a fixed value.

I had changed it back to 7.3 in the server and it seems fine.

Any one has faced the issue before?

Comment: Are you able to trace which core PHP functions are used in the process from data creation to DB save? Also check the PHP database interface Laravel class incase something is going on there (but I can't think what)

Comment: funny enough, the code is working as expected in PHP 7.4 on local. 
The only change I made on the server is PHP 7.3 after we wasted the whole day on the issue.

Comment: the value in the db, `"product_id":"701563066","inventory_id":"-27590470"` is this echoed from php or is it the same in the db table itself (when u check from a dbm)? in some earlier versions of php and mysql there were bigint display issues and sometimes you had to convert the int value to string before forwarding it to php..

Comment: this might be helpful as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16374568/php-mysql-bigint-issue